# Need to use the database name while creating a role

Tags: sql, role

I need to create 2 database roles (need to write the script for this task) `databasename_dbo_reader` and `databasename_dbo_writer` for all the databases on a server.

I have tried the following:

```
Declare @databasename sysname
SELECT @databasename = (SELECT DB_NAME())
exec ('CREATE ROLE' + @databasename + '_DBO_WRITER')
```

but it is throwing some syntax errors. Please help.

Comment: Which syntax error is it throwing? (if that is what you meant by "throughing")

Comment: Which database vendor are you using (e.g. SQL Server, Oracle, mysql)?

Comment: Seriously, the text of the syntax errors would be nice. Why are you keeping the information a secret?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put a space after ROLE like this:

```
exec ('CREATE ROLE ' + @databasename + '_DBO_WRITER')
```